# ASP.NET - How do you escape an apostrophe with a slash to insert in a database

Tags: asp.net, fckeditor

I am not sure how to escape an apostrophe with a slash. I am using fckeditor and fckeditor replaces all  single apostrophes with double apostrophes. My code is doing the same thing so when I view the content there are two apostrophe in the html. I thought that I could escape the apostrophe with a slash and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace double quote with

This code 9&quot; x 9&quot; with give you output as 9" X 9"

And if your database row contain single apostrophe, you can display by assigning that value to lable controls text property and it should work without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [list of HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) you should use `&apos;` (but this will apparantly not work in IE) or `&#39;`.

You can find more on the [HTML Symbol Entities Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_symbols.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You should replace with

```
&quot;
```

which is the best and sometimes only way to store quotaiton marks in text fragments.